# -Error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy haciendo un programa muy simple en el que consiste en medir los metros cuadrados de una habitación. El problema es en esta línea de Código: `print ("Su habitación mide en superficie " + (largo*ancho) + "metros cuadrados")` me da este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/scarl/OneDrive/Documentos/Carlos/Programación/Python/Proyectos Enseñanza/(14) MedidorDeAreas.py", line 6, in <module>
    print ("Su habitación mide en superficie " + (largo*ancho) + "metros cuadrados")
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Me preguntaba si alguien me puede ayudar a resolver el problema, muchas gracias. Si es de ayuda les dejo aquí el código completo

```
print ("Introduzca las medidas en metros cuadrados: ¿Cuál es el largo? ")
largo = str(float(input ()))
print ("¿Cuál es el ancho?")
ancho = str (float(input ()))

print ("Su habitación mide en superficie " + (largo*ancho) + "metros cuadrados")
```

Answer (score 0):

Te envió un código que me funciono basándome en el tuyo:

```
print ("Introduzca las medidas en metros cuadrados: ¿Cuál es el largo? ")
largo = float(input ())
print ("¿Cuál es el ancho?")
ancho = float(input ())

print ("Su habitación mide en superficie {} metros cuadrados".format(largo*ancho))
```

Básicamente, quite la conversion de strings y tambien use un `format` para que lo pudieras visualizar en terminal. Espero sea lo que buscabas.

¡Saludos!

Comment: Gracias! Ya lo solucioné con tu ayuda, muchas gracias Ricardo!

Comment: De nada Carlos que bueno que te sirvió. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, ¿si puedes podrías evaluar mi respuesta? ¡Gracias!